# Unable to fetch data from Zkteco device to 3rd party application

Tags: zkteco

I'm using

```
Ver 6.60 May 13 2020
CKII204760276
ZAM170_TFT
MiniTA
```

I'm unable to fetch data from the device
The data in the device is stored properly, but while trying to retrieve it I'm getting wrong output

I'm using pyzk library.
I'm able to recieve other details like users, password, device info and all
**But when using get_attendance() method to fetch data from the device **

```
attendances = conn.get_attendance()
```

**the output data is wrong.**

Is there any step or method which i'm missing during the retrival process, Please give me some insights about this

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from github issues

Well the problem was I was trying to fetch data using these parameters during connection request

```
zk = ZK(ip=ip, port=int(port), password=device_password, force_udp=True, ommit_ping=False)
```

It should have been this, **force_udp=False**

```
zk = ZK(ip=ip, port=int(port), password=device_password, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
```